# Object with values aligned to the same type but with different generics for each key in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

Let's assume that I have a generic type like this one:

```
type Value<T = any> = {
   component: ComponentType<T>,
   getDuration: (input: T) => void
}
```

And I need to create config value with this shape:

```
type ConfigType = {
    [k: string]: Value
}
```

Is it possible to add some type inferring for each value and it won't be possible for example to create this value:

```
const config: ConfigType = {
   Default: {
      component: (props: Prop1) => null,
      getDuration: (props: Prop2) => void <-- not valid since Prop1 <> Prop2
   },
   Template1: {
      component: (props: Prop3) => null,
      getDuration: (props: Prop3) => void <-- valid 
   }

}
```

And it would be cool if I extracted a config by a key and TS may infer its type without any:

```
  config[Default].component --> ComponentType<Prop1> and not ComponentType<Any>
```

I've tried to do smth in this way but it does not help:

```
type ConfigTemplates<Config extends { [k: string]: Value<unknown> }> =
Config extends Record<string, Value>
? {
    [templateName in string]: Config[templateName] extends Value<
      infer Props
    >
      ? Value<Props>
      : never;
  }
: never;
```

Comment: What is `ComponentType`?

Comment: @Behemoth it is a type from react

Comment: Could be a custom type as well in another context.

Comment: ComponentType it's a React Component and yep here it does not matter what type it is

Comment: well it actually does, only person who is aware of react can determine that `ComponentType` accepts type of the props.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wX1LON) matches your needs?